# Enforcing tag naming convention in svn

Tags: shell, svn, naming, svn-hooks, tagname

I am trying to write a pre commit hook script to enforce a tag naming convention like this `<application>_<project>_<version>_<iteration>` using a shell script.
Can anyone guide me to a doc/link reference which I can follow and can create one.
I have already gone through many links but it didn't work for me

I am trying to do something like this:

ERROR=`$SVNLOOK changed $REPO -t $REV |$EGREP "^A.+?/([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\1-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?-(dev|rc[0-9]+|final)/.*$" |$WC -l`

Need help in regex(EGREP) part so that I can create it.

Comment: tag name like this <application>_<project>_<version>_<iteration>

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall will be hooks executed after pure server-side copies (and too lazy to RTFM or check it by hand), but anyway

In hook you have to use `svnlook` command with different subcommands

Because hooks are repository-wide your first check will be "Is it commit to `/tags` or to another subtree of repository" `svnlook dirs-changed` (try command by hand in order to see output for different revisions, in case of good OS `svnlook dirs-changed |grep tags` will answer on question)

In case of commit into /tags you have to get and check name of (created) subdir inside `/tags`. Here server-side tagging and tagging from WC give (at least for me) different results

**svnlook dirs-changed**

Server-side tagging

```
>svnlook dirs-changed z:\repo
tags/
```

WC-tagging

```
>svnlook dirs-changed z:\repo
tags/
tags/App_Main_1.0.0_2/
tags/App_Main_1.0.0_2/1/
tags/App_Main_1.0.0_2/1/2/
```

**svnlook changed**

Server-side tagging

```
>svnlook changed z:\repo
A   tags/App_Main_1.0.0_1/
```

WC-tagging

```
>svnlook changed z:\repo
A   tags/App_Main_1.0.0_2/
U   tags/App_Main_1.0.0_2/1/2/c.txt
U   tags/App_Main_1.0.0_2/1/b.txt
U   tags/App_Main_1.0.0_2/a.txt
```

and such noticeable differences are observed under **identical tree** within tags

```
>svnlook tree z:\repo
...
 tags/
  App_Main_1.0.0_1/
   1/
    2/
     c.txt
    b.txt
   a.txt
  App_Main_1.0.0_2/
   1/
    2/
     c.txt
    b.txt
   a.txt
...
```

I think, instead of adding some logic inside hook (but you *may try* to use `svnlook changed | head -n 1` for both types of tags: catch only first line of output with name of created tag in it), you have to enforce strict tagging-policy "Tag only trunk's HEAD (use server-side copy)".

In this case test will be shorter and reabable, something like `svnlook changed | grep -q -E REGEXP` (there building REGEXP for testing convention `<application>_<project>_<version>_<iteration>` is your task) plus|minus some details

Comment: thnx 4 such a detailed explanation.
I believe u want me 2 try like this

Comment: ERROR=`$SVNLOOK changed $REPO -t $REV |$EGREP "^A.+?/([a-z0-9_]+)/tags/\1-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?-(dev|rc[0-9]+|final)/.*$" |$WC -l`